# get all strings defined in an apk

Tags: android, apk

Is there a quick way to get all the strings defined in an apk?

I am doing something like this:

```
aapt d --values resources app.apk
```

I am not sure if it gives me all the strings.

If there is any easier way to parse the strings please let me know.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can change "resources" for "strings" and you will have it. Use:

```
aapt d --values strings [APK_FILE]
```

This will dump all the strings on the apk. The dump includes the string resources that is what you are looking for.

This also includes strings generated by the system like the path to resources (res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png by example).

Answer (score 6):

This will decompress the whole APK including turning the files back into the directory hierarchy you expect from an Android project.

<s>http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/</s> (deprecated)

http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/install/

To use type

```
apktool d YourApp.apk
```

Results will go into a folder named YourApp

Answer (score 2):

I found another perhaps simpler way to do this for a particular xml file.

```
aapt d xmlstrings app.apk xmlfile
```

Comment: it said that it can't find the "xmlfile" . also, i don't understand what exactly is missing from your original command, as it seems it writes a lot of things...

Comment: You should give the actual name (with full path) of the xmlfile. For example, "AndroidManifest.xml". You could use the original command from question as well but that searches through the entire apk (not a particular file) -- so it depends on your use case. Also, this answer gives much cleaner results.

Comment: i see, but how could you know the name of the files? wouldn't you need to extract/open the apk file as a zipped file?

Comment: yes, you would need to use a zip/jar utility to get the names of files. But since these files are encoded in a binary format, you cannot read them manually after extraction. So this command comes handy there. Of course, utilities like apktool and androguard can decode the entire xmlfiles and present them in human-readable form - so that would certainly work as well but I feel it is more work if you don't need to study the whole file.

Comment: i've recently looked for apkTools, and found out it's gone from the XDA forums. i wonder how it's like. do you know of a good tool with a UI and not just something that is 100% in console ?

Comment: Not sure if there is anything free out there. You may look at IDA Pro for that. BTW, apktool is at http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/. Once properly set up, to dissassemble an apk, you just need to do `apktool d <apkfile>`

Answer (score 1):

You could try this on a Linux system:

```
$ strings yourfile.spk
```

This will parse out all ASCII characters over a certain length (4 bytes by default) but you can alter those lengths with command-line parameters.

Scanning an .apk like this will give you a LOT of garbage though, as it will find any printable characters in a string and dump it to your screen. Trying this on an APK of my own, though, I see references to GIF images, XML images, basically, anything you reference by filename in your /res/ resource path. No mentions of function names, etc., obviously since that all gets compiled down to machine language.

If you need just xml file references, etc., you could pipe your request through grep, like this:

```
$ strings yourfile.spk | grep xml$
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think one problem with this is that the apk is compressed and so not all strings will come out properly. Moreover, as you pointed out one will also get lot of non strings stuff such as the XML entities and attributes. There may still be some value in uncompressing the apk and then following this approach.